# Remove date folder on uploaded files

Tags: 8, files

Currently the path where the files are saved looks like this: www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/[date when the file is uploaded]/[filename].

Is there anyway to remove the "date when the file is uploaded" directory and save it directly on the files directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes You can just follow few steps given below :

1. Go to Structure > Content-Type
2. Click on Manage Fields of  {{Custom Content Type}}.
3. Edit the file field . From File directory remove [date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m].
4. And you will end up with storing files under files directory

Answer (score 2):

Also you can add your File directory name in file field configuration to save your specific uploded files in your directory under sites/default/files/[your directory ] path